# Python "Hello World" for Libreoffice-calc and Openoffice-calc

Tags: python, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

There is a python-helloworld example for Libre/Openoffice-writer (which is included in Libreoffice 4.1.6.2:

```
def HelloWorldWriter( ):
    """Prints the string 'Hello World(in Python)' into the current document"""
#get the doc from the scripting context which is made available to all scripts
    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
#check whether there's already an opened document. Otherwise, create a new one
    if not hasattr(model, "Text"):
        model = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(
            "private:factory/swriter","_blank", 0, () )
#get the XText interface
    text = model.Text
#create an XTextRange at the end of the document
    tRange = text.End
#and set the string
    tRange.String = "Hello World (in Python)"
    return None
```

That script checks for an open writer document, creates a new one if one does not exist and outputs a string into that document.

Is there something similar for Libreoffice/Openoffice-calc?

Ideally, it should include:

```
· Read a table cell
· Write a table cell
· Save as ODT/XLS/CSV
```

Answer (score 1):

For open office check it :
http://stuvel.eu/ooo-python : http://www.apidev.fr/blog/2011/07/18/utiliser-openoffice-avec-python/ the explanation is in french but check the code :

```
import os, sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
#This is required in order to make pyuno usable with the default python interpreter under windows
#Some environment varaible must be modified

#get the install path from registry
import _winreg
value = _winreg.QueryValue(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\OpenOffice.org\UNO\InstallPath')
install_folder = '\\'.join(value.split('\\')[:-1]) 

#modify the environment variables
os.environ['URE_BOOTSTRAP'] = 'vnd.sun.star.pathname:{0}\\program\\fundamental.ini'.format(install_folder)
os.environ['UNO_PATH'] = install_folder+'\\program\\'
sys.path.append(install_folder+'\\Basis\\program')
paths = ''
for path in ("\\URE\\bin;", "\\Basis\\program;"):
    paths += install_folder + path
os.environ['PATH'] =  paths+ os.environ['PATH']
import uno
```

using the calc :

```
class UnoClient:
def __init__(self):
    localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
    resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
    self.smgr = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager")
def create_document(self, app):
    remoteContext = self.smgr.getPropertyValue("DefaultContext")
    desktop = self.smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",remoteContext)
    url = "private:factory/{0}".format(app)
    return desktop.loadComponentFromURL(url,"_blank", 0, () )
```

you should use it like that :

```
calc = UnoClient().create_document('scalc') #cree un nouveau classeur
sheet = calc.getSheets().getByIndex(0) #1ere feuille du classeur
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0).setString("Salut") #Un texte
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 1).setValue(3.14) #Un nombre
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).setFormula("=SUM(2+2)") #Une formule
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).CellBackColor = int("ff7f00", 16) #Couleur  RGB de fond
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).CharUnderline = 1 # Souligne
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).CharHeight = 16 #Taille de la police
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).CharWeight = 150 #Gras
sheet.getCellByPosition(0, 2).CharPosture = 2 #Italique
```

And check it ! http://oosheet.hacklab.com.br/